# How can I use a TP-LINK WiFi USB interface in OS X Lion?

Tags: wifi, usb

I happen to have a TP-LINK TL-WN821N (it's a WiFi USB stick) around. Is there any chance to get that working on a Mac mini running OS X Lion?

There are no official drivers but it seems there are some kind of drivers for the ATHEROS AR9170+AR9102 chipset from other vendors like Ralink.

Comment: "We are sorry that no plan to release TL-WN821N driver for MAC OS at present." - TP-LINK representant.

Comment: I wonder how hard it would be to port http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ar9170 to OS X.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** The below hack worked when using [D-Link's DWA-130 Rev. D drivers](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=566) instead of the DWA-160 ones. Compatible drivers using the same chipset were identified with the help of the [WikiDevi](http://www.wikidevi.com) database.

---

A quick Google search shows that [someone has had success](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=172383) in using [D-Links DWA-160 driver](http://www.dlink.com/products/?tab=3&pid=DWA-160&rev=DWA-160) (which uses the [same chipset](http://wikidevi.com/wiki/D-Link_DWA-160_rev_A2)), although not without some minor hacking to make the driver recognize the different hardware IDs:

- Install driver package
- Extract kernel extension from installer:

  - **Show Package Contents** of the installer
  - [unarchive](http://unarchiver.c3.cx/) **Archive.pax.gz**
  - grab **AtherosOtusMac.kext**
- Edit plist and change or add your device id and product id converted to decimal (illustrated below):

  - **Show Package Contents** of **AtherosOtusMac.kext**
  - Open **Info.plist** within (using either Xcode or a text or XML editor)
  - Open **System Information**, find your TP-Link under USB and note down **Product ID** and **Vendor ID**
  - Convert both numbers from hexadecimal to decimal (you can use Calculator.app)
  - Replace **idProduct** and **idVendor** on the first model with your numbers
- Use [kext helper](http://cheetha.net/) to install your modified **AtherosOtusMac.kext**
- use **DWA-160.app** (in `/Applications/Utilies`) to connect

Although considering the price of a new Wifi USB stick with OS X drivers, this may not be worth the effort, unless you're doing this sort of thing for fun :-)

Illustration of the plist step (with my USB mouse as example, because I don't have a TL-WN821N laying around):
[image: Plist step illustrated]

Comment: This looks like an excellent answer! Unfortunately I can't seem to get past the first step. The installation of the driver for D-Links DWA-160 driver fails on my OS X Lion. At the download page D-Link states "Supports Mac OS 10.4 and 10.5." so I might be out of luck.

Comment: Recommendations for 802.11n compatible WiFi USB sticks with OS X drivers would be appreciated. My old Mac mini only supports 802.11g.

Comment: You can try anyways, the only thing the installation actually does is put the DWA-160.app in your Utilities folder - and you can easily extract that from the Installer in step 2 instead. It will likely not work if you're running a 64-bit kernel though.

Comment: For replacement hardware, the [BearExtender Mac](http://store.bearextender.com/products/bearextender-for-mac) comes highly recommended and with Lion drivers. It's slightly pricier than the average "stick" form-factor device, but has a couple useful advanced features such as an external antenna connector and a clip. If you just want a normal "stick" with 802.11n and up to date drivers (including 64-bit Lion), the [Zyxel NWD2105](http://www.zyxel.com/products_services/nwd2105.shtml) should be available for very little money.

Comment: You were right about that I could reach the AtherosOtusMac.kext anyway. Then I followed every step of your instruction and everything looked just fine until I started the DWA-160.app. It sasys "Connecting..." and then never connects to anything.

Comment: I have a 32-bit Kernel.

Comment: I tried another, older, TP-LINK WN821N stick (productid 4098 instead of 28693 as the newer one has, same vendorid 3315). And with that it actually connects but only for a couple of seconds. After a few connect/disconnect loops it crashes.

Comment: I've noticed there are [different](http://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN821N_v1) [revisions](http://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN821N_v2) of the WN821N around, with the [latest](http://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN821N_v3) (v3) having a different chipset: AR9002U-2NG. That may be why the older works (partially) with that driver, but the newer one does not. For the newer one (productID 0x7015/28693), [this page](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k_htc/devices) lists devices that use the same chips. Maybe you can find a driver amongst those.

Comment: For the older model (productID 0x1002/4098) there's a similar list [here](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/carl9170). If neither of those work, you're down to writing/porting your own driver, or simply forking over the $10 for a new stick (see recommendations above).

Comment: Personally, for fixed, wired devices, I prefer to use a Powerline adapter and save the wireless for truly mobile devices.  Especially if I'm going to be streaming video.  Been using one with my TiVo for years.  Buy from Amazon because it can be trial an error to find a brand and model that work with your particular room/electrical layout and you want free return/exchange options. I've been using NetGear, never got Zyxel to work but that was years ago. Newer, better, cheaper stuff out now.

Comment: Woohaa! I removed everything Atheros-related from /System/Library/Extensions and then I downloaded the Netgear DWA-130 D drivers for Mac OS X (it seems to be the same as for DWA-160). I patched the Info.plist and followed your instructions above. This time it worked! Thanks a lot for all of your excellent help @IngmarHupp

Comment: @OldPro I'm with you and powerline adapters has certainly crossed my mind!

Comment: It's not Netgear but D-Link DWA-130 REVD sorry for the typo. http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=566

Comment: I looked on the site, but there are only Windows drivers for Rev D. The other revisions are based on other chips. I'm now on a Ralink G stick, but would love to make the 300mbps one work. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Seems I messed up again. The filename of the driver I managed to get installed (by making the changes mentioned above) is DWA160_MAC_Driver_v_4.0.0.10.zip but I could swear I got it for the DWA-130...