# How to use TL-WN823N USB adapter on Mavericks

Tags: macos, wifi, usb

So after a long search on the webs I've found some questions regarding this specific USB adapter on a Mac. It appears some people were using the [driver of a D-Link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48459/how-can-i-use-a-tp-link-wifi-usb-interface-in-os-x-lion) and other [guy made it work](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131602/sunflower-mac-running-osx-10-4-needing-driver-for-usb-wifi-dongle-such-as-tl-w) by using the drivers on the [Tp-Link website](http://www.tp-link.us/support/download/?model=TL-WN823N&version=V1).

The problem is that when downloading the latest driver from the website, it doesnt work! the Installer asks me if I want to install for all the users and then the "Install" button is unclickable.

[image: Install button greyed out]

Also trying the "Standard Install" returns the same result:
[image: Standard Install with grey install button]

Hope anybody can help me.

Comment: I have the same problem, Im installed Pacifist and extracted kext folders, and moved /system/library/extensions/ but nothing ocurred

Comment: @hectorsuarez I downloaded an app from Tp-Link that makes the job. "Wireless Network Utility". Obviously, you first need the drivers that you already cpied. And then you just need to install that app and use it to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either wait for TP-Link to update its driver,

Or use something like [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/) to extract those `kext` folders, and move it to `/system/library/extensions`

Comment: after using pacifist, u will find the files automatically installed in the correct location (i.e /system/library/extensions), the USB Device will start flickering and you need to open the installed program "Wireless Network Utility"