# How can I use a TP-LINK TL-WN722N WiFi adapter in Yosemite?

Tags: wifi, macos, driver

I'm aware that there is no OSX driver provided by TP-LINK for the TL-WN722N, but if I'm referring to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48459/how-can-i-use-a-tp-link-wifi-usb-interface-in-os-x-lion), some people had success with other devices in the same situation.

Is there any way to use this adapter in Yosemite ?
Any workaround or hack ?

[EDIT : OSX updated to "El Capitan" : still no driver...]

Comment: Try going with the last OS-X driver available. While somewhat different that a WiFi adapter, I had the same issue with a printer recently, so I downloaded the Snow Leopard driver for the printer and Yosemite then recognized the printer and everything worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, no OS-X driver was ever released by TP-LINK for this product even for "old" versions of OS-X.